# java: one synchronized vs more synchronized around the same code

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized

is one synchronized better than a lot of synchronized?

```
synchronized(this)
{
   CODE1
   CODE2 // uncritically code, short duration
   CODE3
   CODE4 // uncritically code, short duration
   CODE5
}
```

VS

```
synchronized(this)
{
   CODE1
}

CODE2 // uncritically code, short duration

synchronized(this)
{
   CODE3
}

CODE4 // uncritically code, short duration

synchronized(this)
{
   CODE5
}
```

the following applies: the synchronized blocks so small as possible, like i coded in my secound example.

But is that right in any case? 
If the uncritcally code snippets a in the duration short enoguh, maybe my program is more performant if i dont lock unlock lock unlock and so on?

Comment: You'll never know without benchmarking your specific case.

Comment: This is really context specific. What if CODE4 is somehow related to CODE1 or CODE2? Is the performance gain/loss on that really important overall the whole prorgram?

Comment: the uncritically code means, that code4 is not related to something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JVM’s optimizer is capable of joining adjacent synchronized blocks if it helps performance, but it can’t do the opposite, as splitting it would change the semantic.

See the Java SE 6 Performance White Paper, [2.1.2  Lock coarsening](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/6-performance-137236.html#2.1.2)

> There are some patterns of locking where a lock is released and then reacquired within a piece of code where no observable operations occur in between. The lock coarsening optimization technique implemented in hotspot eliminates the unlock and relock operations in those situations […]. It basically reduces the amount of synchronization work by enlarging an existing synchronized region.

<sup>the reference to Java 6 shows that this is not even a brand new feature</sup>
So if you know that there’s uncritical code and the entire code works with temporarily releasing the lock (which may have the state altered in-between by other threads), then use multiple synchronized blocks, to tell the JVM and the human readers that CODE2 and CODE4 are not critical.

This follows the typical pattern of letting the runtime optimizer make the right trade-offs, as it knows more about the actual situation, i.e. hardware and actual application behavior, than us.

Answer (score 1):

You have not given enough information to answer the question.

Presumably, CODE1, CODE3, and CODE5 access data that is shared with other threads because if they did not, then there would be no point in using `synchronized`.

So, what would happen if thread B tries to use the shared data after thread A has performed CODE1, but not yet performed CODE3 or CODE5? What would happen if thread B tries to use the shared data after thread A has performed CODE1 and CODE3, but not CODE5? If any bad thing could happen as a result, then you need to perform all three of the CODEs in *the same* synchronized block, and also, whatever thread B is doing with that same shared data, it also must do it in a similar `synchronized(this)` block.

---

If CODE1, CODE3, and CODE5 are fully independent of each other, then my gut reaction would be to use several smaller `synchronized` blocks---especially so if any of the five CODEs takes any significant amount of time.  I like to keep `synchronized` blocks as short (timewise) as possible.

But if the performance is really critical, then you ought to *measure* it and prove to yourself which is the better way.